# how to animate a header image to go from left to right in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, css-transitions

I have `background-image` which is a plane and I just want it to go from flying in right to flying out left.

Please help me to do this, I'm working on a WordPress site.

```css
#header {
    background-image: url(http://www.stblaizerc.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/headerplane.png);
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

Take a look [here](http://www.stblaizerc.co.za/) if you want to see.

Comment: I don't see any CSS in the code you shared that might achieve what you want. So the question is, what have you tried ? did you take a look at css animations ?It should be very easy to do it after you read the docs as it's a pretty basic animation.

Comment: #header {
    background-image: url(http://www.stblaizerc.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/headerplane.png);
     margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
 -webkit-animation-name: slidein; }

@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
            from {
                margin-right: 100%;
              
            }

            to {
                margin-right: 0%;
               
            }
        }

Comment: this is completely reversed hahasorry i am still learning as i go

Comment: well if this is reversed. Just reverse the styles :) from <-> to